# How to stop or exit from the app, when user click on notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to stop or exit from my application when the user press the notification icon, here is my code. with this code i can able to open my main activity by pressing notification icon. all i want is someone to change my existing code, plz help me

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
  builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic);
  builder.setContentTitle("RadioPlanet");
    builder.setContentText("Touch here to stop");int mll=001;
   PendingIntent contentIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);



    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
  NotificationManager mNotification=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  mNotification.notify(mll,builder.build());
```

my package name is `com.hackerinside.jaisonjoseph.radioplanet`

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with notifications, but here is a suggestion:

Create a new activity. For this example, I will call it MainActivityStop. From the notification, send a PendingIntent to MainActivityStop. In MainActivityStop, create a new intent and putExtra. EXample:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityStop.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtra("stop", true);
startActivity(i);
```

To receive it:

```
boolean stop = false;

try{
    stop = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("stop", false);
}catch(Exception e){
//ignore this. If it gets here, the boolean cannot be found. It may never go to the catch block, it is a safety precaution
}

(...) Do whatever you do to stop or exit.
```

Comment: i did not understand

Comment: The PendingIntent in the notification should link to a different activity. The different activit then links to MainActivity  and sends a boolea nvalue set to "true". On boot of MainActivity, see if stop is true and then you stop or exit the app

Comment: can u write the full code (from creating MainActivityStop)

Comment: This is so easy, it can be done in less than 20 lines(meaning write it yourself. The key code is in the answer, the rest you have to do). MainActivityStop will contain onCreate and an intent that leads to MainActivity(intent code is in the answer). In your notificaiton, change your PendingIntent to MainActivityStop. In MainActivity, you receive the boolean value and take appropriate action

Comment: i am just a beginner so, basically i don't know how to declare a new activity calss inside main activity

Comment: You create a new Java file with the activity. [Here is the official documentation on creating new Activities and using intent to swap between them](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity)

Comment: So i should create an activity without layout file and i have to call the activity with your code ?

Comment: Yes. You do not need a layout as it is just a redirect